# Assigning values to cells using a conditional in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I am new to the VBA world and I am having problems with my code.

I am trying to assign values to a row with the help of a conditional, in short is that when the value of `Cells(Row1, k)` is greater than 0 in the cell `Cells(Row2, k)` I run a code already functional SQL and I sign the returned value, and if not I assign 0. The problem is that when I perform this code only the first value of the row is changed.

Here is a summary of my code:

```vb
For k = 2 To 25
    val = proc.Cells(Fila1, k)
    
    If val > 0 Then
        CodigoSQL = ....
                
        Fila = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Titulo1", proc.Columns(1), 0)
        Celda = "B" & CStr(Fila)
    
        Set FI = cnxnsic.Execute(CodigoSQL)
    
        If Not FI.EOF Then
            Do While Not FI.EOF
                proc.Range(Celda).CopyFromRecordset FI
            Loop
        Else
            msg = MsgBox("Error en la consulta Configuracion_Arranque_Utilizado", vbOKOnly, "Error Consulta")
        End If
    Else
        Fila = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Titulo2", proc.Columns(1), 0)
        Celda = "B" & CStr(Fila)
        proc.Range(Celda).Value = 0
```